# Allow user-defined script in Ruby/Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, scripting, eval

A predefined set of objects has to be aggregated into a new object. However I want the users to specify a custom function for that.

Now the naive approach would be

```
def foo; end

objects = [1,2,3]
# result = eval(user_script)
result = eval("objects.inject {|sum, n| sum + n }")
```

What I **obviously** do not want to do! I read about `$SAFE = 4` (see [here](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/taint.html)), but I'm not sure that this is enough. Especially because the user-defined script will still be able to call other functions like `foo`. I only want to allow access to basic non-dangerous Ruby core-functions.

Are there any facilities for Ruby to allow safe execution of user-defined scripts? I doesn't need to be Ruby syntax. It would be nice, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen Sven Fuch's safemode plugin ([overview here](http://www.artweb-design.de/2008/2/17/sending-ruby-to-the-jail-an-attemp-on-a-haml-safemode))?  Here's the [page](http://github.com/svenfuchs/safemode) at GitHub.

Instead of blacklisting dangerous methods, which is what $SAFE does, it parses the incoming code and removes any method not on a whitelist. The plugin comes with a predefined whitelist that can be seen in [this file](http://github.com/svenfuchs/safemode/blob/master/lib/safemode/core_jails.rb).

I've personally never used this plugin but the author is active in the Ruby community and I'm sure he'd answer any questions you asked.

Comment: This is great! Difficult to find such things in the rubyverse.

Answer (score 0):

The best lock in the world won't prevent you from being robbed blind if you choose to give everyone in the world the key.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I only give moderators the right to add such code.